# how to test Database connection with Spring Bean

Tags: database, spring, testing, autowired

Test Database connection Spring

how can I test DB connection with spring bean, autowired.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_jdbc_example.htm

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:/bean.xml"})
public class TestDataBase {

  @Autowired
  private DataSource ds;

  private StudentJDBCTemplate  StudentJDBCTemplateObj;

  @Test
  public void test() {

    StudentJDBCTemplateObj = new StudentJDBCTemplate();
    StudentJDBCTemplateObj.setDataSource(ds);

    Student st = StudentJDBCTemplateObj.getStudent(1);

    Integer expected = 1; 
    Integer actual = st.getId();

    assertEquals(expected, actual); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Does not look wrong. What's the problem? Any error message, exception? If so, you should post your bean.xml if it's different from the linked example.

Comment: I have tried, and I got the problem is my table, my table was Students, and I wrote Student, afterthat I have done run and it works good, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: but I have a nother idea,
Without @autowired, and without @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:/bean.xml"}), we can make test simply, as the following , 

  private StudentJDBCTemplate  StudentJDBCTemplateObj;

Comment: but I have a nother idea,
Without at autowired, and without @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:/bean.xml"}), we can make test simply, as the following , 

  @Test
 public void testDB{
 
  DataSource ds;
        ApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext ("src/test/java/test-bundle-context.xml");
        StudentJDBCTemplate StudentJDBCTemplateObj = (SynonymReqMod)context.getBean("StudentJDBCTemplateBean");

    StudentJDBCTemplateObj.setDataSource(ds);
    Student st = StudentJDBCTemplateObj.getStudent(1);